# Using QNetworkRequest with XP-Dev

Tags: qt, qnetworkrequest

I am trying to use QNetworkRequest with XP-Dev but I am having no luck.

I have posted up mu code but with certain company details omitted.

I get a reply error code of 99, unknown network error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("https://mycomp.xp-dev.com/api/v1/user"));

QJsonObject user;

user.insert("username", "OttoMann");
user.insert("email", "o.mann@springfieldelementary.com");
user.insert("password", "Abdc4312");
user.insert("userRole", "Administrator");

QByteArray jsonstring = QJsonDocument(user).toJson();
QByteArray jsonsize = QByteArray::number(jsonstring.size());

QNetworkAccessManager nam;

req.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
//req.setRawHeader("Content-Length", jsonsize);
req.setRawHeader("X-XPDevToken", "(removed obviously)");

QNetworkReply *reply = nam.post(req, jsonstring);

int count = 0;
while (!reply->isFinished())
{
    qApp->processEvents();
    count++;
}

QNetworkReply::NetworkError  err1 = reply->error();

if (err1 == QNetworkReply::NoError)
{
    QByteArray response_data = reply->readAll();

    QJsonDocument json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);

    int x = 1;
}
else
{
    int error = 1;
}
```

Comment: Update.... I have found an reply->errorString() function that returns

"Error creating SSL context ()"

Comment: Well, that means you are missing the openssl libraries. You must install openssl for your operating system and add the location of the libraries to the (library) path (or directly link your application to openssl)

Comment: Well that worked thanks, but normally a program doesn't run if DLLs are missing.

Comment: That is true. But only, if the library was linked. This is not the case for openssl, Qt uses runtime functions to dynamically load the dll if needed, similar to how Qt plugins work.